Discrepancy between answers from different Estimators in qiskit
After upgrading to qiskit 1.0.0, I tried using different estimators: estimatorv2, qiskit-aer estimator and default primitive estimator. But I get different expectation values with each of them?  Am I doing something wrong? Below is the code that I am using.
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import EstimatorV2

seed = 20
n_qubits = 2

obs = SparsePauliOp(['ZY', 'YI', 'IY', 'II', 'YY', 'ZY', 'XI', 'YZ', 'ZZ', 'IX'],
              coeffs=[0.64414354+0.j, 0.38074849+0.j, 0.66304791+0.j, 0.16365073+0.j,
 0.96260781+0.j, 0.34666184+0.j, 0.99175099+0.j, 0.2350579 +0.j,
 0.58569427+0.j, 0.4066901 +0.j])

# Ansatz
circuit = TwoLocal(
    n_qubits,
    ["rx", "ry", "rz"],
    ["cx"],
    "linear",
    reps=3,
)

params = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2 * np.pi, size=circuit.num_parameters)

# Estimator V2
aer_sim = AerSimulator(method="automatic")

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=aer_sim, optimization_level=1)
isa_qc = pm.run(circuit)
est = EstimatorV2(backend=aer_sim)
pub = (isa_qc, obs, params)
result = est.run([pub]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from Estimatorv2: {result[0].data.evs}")

# Aer Estimator
est = AerEstimator(run_options={"seed": seed}, approximation=False)
result = est.run([isa_qc], [obs], [params]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from AerEstimator: {result.values[0]}")

# Primitive Estimator
est = Estimator(options={"seed": seed})
result = est.run([isa_qc], [obs], [params]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from qiskit.primitve Estimator: {result.values[0]}")

This gives me different result:
Expectation value from Estimatorv2: 0.4890561498339845
Expectation value from AerEstimator: 0.40740949503906254
Expectation value from qiskit.primitve Estimator: 0.4549841069144796

I would expect all of them to be very close to each other.

You are seeing the discrepancy because qiskit.primitives Estimator gives an ideal result by default whereas the other Estimators are using shots.
Another way you can get reproducible expectation values is by properly using seed value in all the estimators. Here is how you can do this:

For EstimatorV2, you can use the seed_estimator option to set a seed value.
For qiskit_aer.primitives Estimator, you can set the approximation=True so that it calculates ideal expectation value (just like qiskit.primitives Estimator).

Here is your code with all the changes made:
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.primitives import Estimator as AerEstimator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import EstimatorV2

seed = 20
n_qubits = 2

obs = SparsePauliOp(['ZY', 'YI', 'IY', 'II', 'YY', 'ZY', 'XI', 'YZ', 'ZZ', 'IX'],
              coeffs=[0.64414354+0.j, 0.38074849+0.j, 0.66304791+0.j, 0.16365073+0.j,
 0.96260781+0.j, 0.34666184+0.j, 0.99175099+0.j, 0.2350579 +0.j,
 0.58569427+0.j, 0.4066901 +0.j])

# Ansatz
circuit = TwoLocal(
    n_qubits,
    ["rx", "ry", "rz"],
    ["cx"],
    "linear",
    reps=3,
)

params = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2 * np.pi, size=circuit.num_parameters)

# Estimator V2
aer_sim = AerSimulator(method="automatic")

pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=aer_sim, optimization_level=1)
isa_qc = pm.run(circuit)
est = EstimatorV2(backend=aer_sim, options={"seed_estimator":seed})  # Here you set the seed_simulator option
pub = (isa_qc, obs, params)
result = est.run([pub]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from Estimatorv2: {result[0].data.evs}")

# Aer Estimator
est = AerEstimator(run_options={"seed": seed}, approximation=True)  # Changed to aproximation=True
result = est.run([isa_qc], [obs], [params]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from AerEstimator: {result.values[0]}")

# Primitive Estimator
est = Estimator(options={"seed": seed})
result = est.run([isa_qc], [obs], [params]).result()
print(f"Expectation value from qiskit.primitve Estimator: {result.values[0]}")

Running this code you get the expectation values which are very close:
Expectation value from Estimatorv2: 1.2858884791699219
Expectation value from AerEstimator: 1.288727373816423
Expectation value from qiskit.primitve Estimator: 1.2887273738164235

